How do I keep multiple animations from affecting each other?
newbie here.
I'm using Blender to make animations for a game character in Unreal.  I've made multiple animations for my character using the Action Editor.
When I switch from Animation A to Animation B, if Animation A has a keyed track that doesn't exist in Animation B, it will preserve whatever the values of Animation A's state when I switch over to Animation B.
For example, one of my animations is a punch, and one is a reaction to being hit.  If I key frames of the legs in the hit reaction, but don't key them in the punch, when I switch from the hit reaction to the punch, the punch is now displaying the legs as they were last seen in the hit reaction.  This persists when I export the files to Unreal.
When I've played with animation in other programs, I'm used to all the tracks resetting to a default state with each new animation, and not having the state of a previous animation affecting the new one.  What should I be doing differently?
Thanks so much!

Select all bones, press Alt G, Alt R, Alt S (Reset Loc, Rot, Scale), load in the action editor the first animation, go to the first frame and press I to insert a keyframe on every bone (Loc, Rot, Scale and Custom Properties, if you have some).
Repeat for every Action to be exported.
